# Drawing aircraft fuselage

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have this image...

[image: Fuselage]

I want to replicate this in LaTeX but also have dimensions in one of the windows. Something like this...

[image: Drawing]

How could I do this using TiKZ whilst also maintaining the feel and shape of an actual aircraft like in the image, and adding the dimensions thing as well?

The 'Draw an aircraft with Tikz' question does not answer this question.

Comment: This seems to be identical to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534026/drawing-aircraft-fuselage  you could edit that question and ask that it be re-opened rather than just posting again.  It does not seem substantially different from the question on drawing a whole aircraft. Rather than just asserting the answers to that do not help it might be better to start with one of the answers there then ask for help adapting it

Comment: why do you want to re-draw the aircraft why not include an image and just draw the dimension arrows over the window?

Answer (score 16):

It is very easy to draw such things, just tedious. For the future I'd kindly ask you to provide some code that at the very least defines the colors, sets some dimensions and so on, so that others do not have to start from scratch.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{wt}{RGB}{210,215,219} % frame top
\definecolor{wb}{RGB}{151,154,162} % frame bottom
\definecolor{w}{RGB}{49,66,89}     % window
\definecolor{pt}{RGB}{242,242,242} % plane top
\definecolor{pb}{RGB}{208,209,213} % plane bottom
\definecolor{wf}{RGB}{85,96,110}   % inner frame
\definecolor{blind}{RGB}{115,119,128}      % blind
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,pics/fuselage/.style={code={
        \tikzset{fuselage/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fuselage/##1}}%
        \fill[w,rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});
        \clip [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2);    
        \fill[blind] (-\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2-\pv{b}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2);
        \fill[wf,xshift=1.3pt,yshift=-1.3pt,even odd rule]
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2)
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});            
        \draw[top color=wt,bottom color=wb,even odd rule] 
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2)
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});            
}},fuselage/.cd,h/.initial=1.4cm,w/.initial=1cm,
    d/.initial=0.7mm,r/.initial=4mm,b/.initial=2mm]
 \path[top color=pt,bottom color=pb] (-4,-3) rectangle (4,3);
 \path foreach \X in {0,...,3} {(-3+2*\X,0.5) pic{fuselage}};
 \draw[|<->|] (1-0.425,0.5) -- (1+0.425,0.5) node[pos=0.75,above]{$a$};
 \draw[|<->|] (1,0.5-0.625) -- (1,0.5+0.625) node[pos=0.75,left]{$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Per request a version with passengers. (These are not necessarily animals, among the Ti*k*Zlings there is a snowman and three beings.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\definecolor{wt}{RGB}{210,215,219} % frame top
\definecolor{wb}{RGB}{151,154,162} % frame bottom
\definecolor{w}{RGB}{49,66,89}     % window
\definecolor{pt}{RGB}{242,242,242} % plane top
\definecolor{pb}{RGB}{208,209,213} % plane bottom
\definecolor{wf}{RGB}{85,96,110}   % inner frame
\definecolor{blind}{RGB}{115,119,128}      % blind
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,pics/fuselage/.style={code={
        \tikzset{fuselage/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fuselage/##1}}%
        \fill[w,rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});
        \clip [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2);    
        \fill[blind] (-\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2-\pv{b}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2);
        \tikzling[scale=0.6,yshift=-2cm]    
        \fill[wf,xshift=1.3pt,yshift=-1.3pt,even odd rule]
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2)
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});            
        \draw[top color=wt,bottom color=wb,even odd rule] 
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}]
            (-\pv{w}/2,-\pv{h}/2) rectangle (\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}/2)
            [rounded corners=\pv{r}-\pv{d}]
            (-\pv{w}/2+\pv{d},-\pv{h}/2+\pv{d}) rectangle (\pv{w}/2-\pv{d},\pv{h}/2-\pv{d});            
}},fuselage/.cd,h/.initial=1.4cm,w/.initial=1cm,
    d/.initial=0.7mm,r/.initial=4mm,b/.initial=3mm]
 \path[top color=pt,bottom color=pb] (-4,-3) rectangle (4,3);
 \path foreach \X in {0,...,3} {(-3+2*\X,0.5) pic{fuselage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These are randomly chosen Ti*k*Zlings, in each compilation you will get a random set. If you do not like this randomness, use `\pgfmathsetseed{<int>}` where `int` is an integer.

Comment: Wow, as if the windows were copied from the photograph!

Comment: @AlexG [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEJfk.png) is a version with photo-realistic passengers. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat way too much time on your hands!

Comment: @Thruston I don't have hands, only claws. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Just for curiosity, could you add the code of the animals picture you've done in the comments please.

Comment: @dave Sure, done.

Comment: This is pure art!

Comment: @Sebastiano No. it is highly unfair. The bear should not have gotten the business class seat!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat But the bears are the same! Are they brother and sister?

Comment: @Sebastiano I really do not know, but the airline must have made a mistake giving them so good seats.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat A note...in your fuselage is missing the long line. Please, can you see the initial picture of the OP?

Comment: @Sebastiano Just add `\draw[gray,thin] (-4,-1.5) -- (4,-1.5);` under `\path[top color=pt,bottom color=pb] (-4,-3) rectangle (4,3);`.

Comment: Unless seats have been seriously rearranged since the last time I was on an airplane, I hope this one is on the ground, because that view of passengers means that they haven't buckled their seat belts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Some time after take-off it is fine to unbuckle, especially if you are as lucky as the Ti*k*Zlings who got upgraded.